# Batch: Rename extension and increment with letter

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Need to know how to rename a file extension

for example:

```
-testAA_1.csv
-testBB_2.csv
-testCC_3.csv
```

to:

```
-testAA.aa1
-testBB.ab1
-testCC.ac1 (all the way to .zz1)
```

the program that writes the .csv file will continually add to the directory, so i need to be able to the search directory for the last incremented extension and start there.

for example:

```
last file changed was testDD_14.csv to testDD.cc1
```

need to run batch again and have the newest files start with the file extension of .cd1

Comment: Read `HELP REN` and `HELP FOR` and try `REN` in a `FOR` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create nextLetter array used to increment letters
set "letter=z"
for %%a in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
   set "nextLetter[!letter!]=%%a"
   set "letter=%%a"
)

rem Initialize extension for the first time
set "lastExt=.zz1"
rem Search directory for the last incremented extension, if any
if exist -test*.??1 for /F %%a in ('dir /B /O-E -test*.??1') do set "lastExt=%%~Xa" & goto continue
:continue
rem Get first and second letters from last extension
set "first=%lastExt:~1,1%"
set "second=%lastExt:~2,1%"

rem Process original files
for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B -test*.csv') do (
   rem Increment extension
   for %%c in (!second!) do set "second=!nextLetter[%%c]!"
   if "!second!" equ "a" for %%c in (!first!) do set "first=!nextLetter[%%c]!"
   rem Rename this file
   ren %%a_%%b %%a.!first!!second!1
)
```

This is a session example output:

```
C:\ dir /B /OE
test.bat
-testAA_1.csv
-testCC_3.csv
-testBB_2.csv
-testCC_3.OK
-testBB_2.OK
-testAA_1.OK

C:\ test.bat

C:\ dir /B /OE
-testAA.aa1
-testBB.ab1
-testCC.ac1
test.bat
-testCC_3.OK
-testBB_2.OK
-testAA_1.OK

C:\ copy *.OK *.csv
-testAA_1.OK
-testBB_2.OK
-testCC_3.OK
        3 archivo(s) copiado(s).

C:\ test.bat

C:\ dir /B /OE
-testAA.aa1
-testBB.ab1
-testCC.ac1
-testAA.ad1
-testBB.ae1
-testCC.af1
test.bat
-testCC_3.OK
-testAA_1.OK
-testBB_2.OK
```

Comment: If you find this answer useful you may select it as Best answer and upvote it when you have enough rep points to do so...

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "tebahpla= z y x w v u t s r q p o n m l k j i h g f e d c b a"
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
FOR /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*_*.csv" '
 ) DO (
  FOR %%x IN (%tebahpla%) DO FOR %%y IN (%tebahpla%) DO (
   IF NOT EXIST "%sourcedir%\test*.%%x%%y1" SET "newext=%%x%%y1"
  )
 REN "%sourcedir%\%%a_%%b" "%%a.!newext!"
)

DIR "%sourcedir%\*.*1"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.